# How remove node ID [nid:n] in NodeReference fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-fapi

This is the same question of this link:

[Removing [nid:n] in nodereference autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515722/removing-nidn-in-nodereference-autocomplete)

According with the first answer (Grayside) I've created my own module and activated. Then I create a new content, I look sth up in the nodereference field and finally select it -> it works (Doesn't appear the [nid:n]).

But, when I view/preview or save or edit the content, the [nid:n] appears again.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the node, it is the theming function for the field that determines what is displayed, so you need to overwrite it, if you want to change the output.

The value when you edit the node, is determined by the `#default_value` property, so you need to change in your `hook_form_alter()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I've found the solution. (At least in my case)

I change the code of this file:

> drupal\modules\cck\cck\modules\nodereference.module

```
function nodereference_autocomplete_value($element, $edit = FALSE)
{
  ...
  // $value .= ' [nid:'. $nid .']';    --> Comment this line
  return array($field_key => $value);
}
```

It works very well! Doesn't appear in any case: Not in selected from the list, nor when save, edit, etc.

Regards!